# Magento 2: How the collect totals is saved to database when adding product to cart?

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, totals

On clicking on **Add-to-cart**, the price is added to cart, in Mini cart it shows **cart subtotal** and this **cart subtotal** is saved in the quote table database.

 So my question is: 
How is these **cart subtotal** is getting saved to database? from which file?

Comment: I Mean Cart subtotal, by observer is saving in database or any other way he is saving the value in quote table database

Answer (score 1):

Take a look the Add to Cart controller `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php`

```
 $this->cart->save();
```

Go to the save method: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart.php`

```
    $this->getQuote()->collectTotals();
    $this->quoteRepository->save($this->getQuote());
```

As we can see, Magento will use `Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository` to save the quote with collect totals to database.

Comment: It is helpful,But i need to know how is cart subtotal is getting stored in quote table,above answer is close that the data is getting saved in quote table,but i need to know only where exactly the cart subtotal is saving from

Comment: @PranayK I think it's better if you debug the code lines above.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh If I am trying to delete item from quote item, then how to execute collect total? I have quote Id, Item id. how do I save?